# No me esta tomando el la cadena del string en la funcion y no imprime nada

Tags: c

¡Buen día!

Tengo una función la cual toma un `string` y convierte todas las minúsculas en mayúsculas. El problema radica en el `main` porque de una manera funciona y de la otra manera en la cuál me lo piden ***(sin inicializar variable en la misma linea)*** no me funciona. Mi `ft_strupcase.c`

```
char    *ft_strupcase(char *str)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
            if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
                    str[i] -= 32;
            i++;
    }
    return (str);
}
```

Y mi `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_strupcase(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    //char str1[] = "I made it"; De esta manera me funciona*

    char str1[100];

    str1[100] = "I made it";                                    
    printf("The sentence is %s\n", ft_strupcase(str1));
}
```

Me lanza el siguiente error.

> main.c:11:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a
>   cast [-Wint-conversion]   str1[100] = "I made it";

He estado leyendo y al parecer tiene que ver con que asigno un entero al puntero sin invocarlo pero no logro sacarlo. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si ya has declarado un array de caracteres, **y no lo has inicializado en la declaración**, tendrás que copiar la cadena usando la función `strncpy` de `string.h` u otra función similar como `strlcpy` o `snprintf`.

Te pongo un ejemplo con strncpy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str1[100];
    strncpy(str1, "I made it\0", 100);                                    
    printf("The sentence is %s\n", str1);
}
```

El primer parámetro de strncpy es la cadena destino, el segundo la cadena a origen, y el tercer parámetro el número de caracteres a copiar.

Lo que no puedes hacer es esto:

```
str1[100] = "I made it";
```

Lo que estás diciendo ahí es que asigne en la posición 100 (vamos mal porque el array iría de 0 a 99) una cadena de caracteres, pero str1[100] es un carácter y no puedes asignar una cadena a un carácter. Y aunque te dejase estarías desbordando el array porque en el array de 100 estarías concatenando los 9 o 10 caracteres de tu cadena.

Esto de aquí:

```
char str1[] = "I made it";
```

Te funciona porque le estás asignando un valor durante la declaración.

EDIT: Respondidendo a la pregunta del comentario, efectivamente, si vas caracter por caracter lo puedes hacer, ten en cuenta que si lo haces así tienes que usar comillas simples, ya  que asignas caracteres en lugar de cadenas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str1[100];
    str1[0] = 'H';
    str1[1] = 'o';
    str1[2] = 'l';
    str1[3] = 'a';
    str1[4] = '\0';
    printf("The sentence is %s\n", str1);
}
```

Comment: Entonces declarando la cadena str1 e ir asignando a cada hueco un caracter y luego imprimir valdria tambien?

Comment: @DarkTemplar He editado la respuesta para incluir esta última pregunta que haces